# Resize WPF ListBox selection box

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, styles, datatemplate

For a project I have implemented a small IntelliSense like control which is nothing than a `ListBox`. Its `DataTemplate` consist of a `StackPanel` holding one `Image` and one `TextBlock`. Nothing else. As you can see in the first screenshot of my control, the selection box of the ListBox selects the whole item (which usually is exactly what one would expect):

[image: Custom ListBox]

However my "stolen" icons from VS11 are low-quality so I wanted to adjust the selection like Visual Studio does:

[image: Visual Studio IntelliSense]

You can see that only the text is selected (the visual representation does ignore the image/icon) and I want to know how I can implement this behavior, too.

*EDIT:* The icons are just GIF files with a transparent background. I will replace them with better ones, but nevertheless I am interestes in how to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Do your images have transparent backgrounds?

Comment: Could you change the background of the TextBlock instead of the whole StackPanel?

Comment: @benjer3: I did not change the BG property of the StackPanel, therefore i do not exactly understand what you would suggest.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood.  At first glance I thought you _weren't_ using a ListBox, and therefore using triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution by replacing the ListBoxItem control template.  In my test I just display two text strings, with the second one highlighted.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Selected" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                         AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" 
                        Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:DataItem}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="c1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="c2"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="../Images/Collapse.png"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Selected}" 
                       Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Page.DataContext>
    <Samples:Page3ViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ListBox 
        Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
        SelectedIndex="2"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

The view model contains a collection of simple data items

```
public class Page3ViewModel
{
    public Page3ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<DataItem>
            {
                new DataItem{Name = "One", Description = "First"},
                new DataItem{Name = "Two", Description = "Second"},
                new DataItem{Name = "Three", Description = "Third"},
                new DataItem{Name = "Four", Description = "Fourth"},
            };
    }
    public IEnumerable<DataItem> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

Giving

[image]

Comment: + 1. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve but I couldn't figure it out. Excellent work.

Comment: +1. I like this solution however in my opinion @Benjamins (updated) solution is a little shorter. Nevertheless both do what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to the way WPF renders each item in the *ListBox*. It uses an *ItemContainerStyle* which wraps each item in a *ListBoxItem*. It is this *ListBoxItem* that contains the content to be displayed (in your case a StackPanel that contains an Image and a TextBlock).

By default, the *ListBoxItem* displays the blue rectangle around **all** content that it displays.

I have come up with a solution but it is a hack. Simply make your image larger and have the background pixel colour match the background colour of the *Listbox* (in my case, white) and use the following XAML.

```
<ListBox Margin="5"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="-2,0,0,0">
                <Image Source="Save-icon.png" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5,8,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is the result:

[image]

**Update**

I have come up with a modification which makes this a little less of a hack.
In my *ItemTemplate* I have surrounded the image with a *Border* which uses binding to get its background colour from it's parent *ListBox*. (The image no longer has a border around it).

Update the XAML to this:

```
<ListBox Margin="5"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         Background="LightSteelBlue">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="-2,0,0,0">
                <Border Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                        Padding="10">
                    <Image Source="Save-icon.png"/>
                 </Border>
                 <TextBlock Margin="5,8,0,0"
                            Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

This is the new result:

[image]

Now all you need to do is update the background colour of the *ListBox* and everything will adjust automatically. E.G.

```
<ListBox Margin="20"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         Background="PeachPuff">
```

[image]

Comment: It still does not color the image background

Comment: My answer clearly states that you need your image to have the image background colour match that of the ListBox.

Comment: I was thinking of this too but it's *inconvenient* to be bound to the BG of the ListBox although I do not know and other workaround. Nevertheless thanks, but I will wait to see whether someone else has another solution; otherwise, I will accept your answer and honor you for your effort.

Comment: It is inconvenient. I am currently working on a solution but cannot currently figure it out. You need some way of communicating where your ItemTemplate content gets put in the ItemContainerStyle which is difficult because you may not know what DataTemplate will be used.