# WPF ListBox SelectionBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a DataTemplate for my WPF ListBox:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogEntry}" x:Key="lineNumberTemplate">
  <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Index" Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Cursor="/LogViewer;component/Template/RightArrow.cur">
      <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=LineNumbersBackgroundColor, ElementName=LogViewerProperty}" Opacity="0.4" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource MyLineNumberText}" x:Name="txtBoxLineNumbers" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource MyTextEditor}" />
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is it possible that the selection box begins not at the beginning (MyLineNumberText) but at MyTextEditor? Sorry I don't know how to describe it in the right way.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, here I found a other good working solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064114/resize-wpf-listbox-selection-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to modify the style of the listbox. If you are using Blend this is easy. Otherwise you could get the style for Listbox and ListboxIten here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=vs.95).aspx

Copy the style to your project and then change the style acordingly.